# Issues with String and Pointer

Tags: c

I have a string which I need to pass to a function like below.

```
scanf("%s%d",&name,&telno);
addatend(telno,name);
```

where

```
char name[MAX];
```

I am getting the following warning :

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’ [-Wformat]
```

I did try to do changes like having one more `char` pointer and point to `name`. But the warning stays.

In the function I have strcpy

```
strcpy(addnode->name,name1);
```

This is coping the `name` from `main` to the `name` in the structure `addnode`. But there is a segmentation fault at this line.

I tried to check in splint (did not have any issues at this line) and valgrind but could not identify my mistake. Hence came here for help. Thanks in advance..

The code:

```
typedef struct Mystruct{
char *name;
int telno;
struct Mystruct *nextp;
}data;

void addatend(int telno1, char* name1)
{
    data *addnode, *previousnode;
    addnode = malloc (sizeof(data));

    if(addnode == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed...Exiting");
        exit(0);
    }

    strcpy(addnode->name,name1);        //error Part of the code.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading a string with `scanf`, the array is passed to the function as a pointer, so you don't need the address-of operator `&`.

---

Regarding your second problem... You need to allocate memory for the destination you copy to as well. Either use `malloc` again (using `strlen(...) + 1`, the `+1` for the string terminator) before the `strcpy`, or use `strdup` which allocates and copies the string:

```
addnode->name = strdup(name1);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I got the warnings cleared but the seg fault stays. Would you like to see the complete code once?

Comment: @Shash Have you allocated memory for `addnode` _and_ `addnode->name`?

Comment: @Shash Please edit your question adding that code, and also the definition of the `data` structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use zero-length array or flexible array member to store the name in your structure. However, it must be the last struct member. Here is how you declare it.

```
typedef struct Mystruct {
    int telno;
    struct Mystruct *nextp;
    char name[];
} data;
```

In the function, you would do

```
data *addnode = malloc(sizeof(data) + strlen(name1) + 1);
strcpy(addnode->name, name1);
```